# Vim highlight all text after multiple "#"

Tags: vim, regex, syntax-highlighting, vimscript

I am trying to make text bold if it appears after a series of `#` hashes. This is the line in my `.vimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt hi header cterm=cyan ctermbg=red
```

and my attempted regular expressions:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt syn match header /\n#+\zs.*\ze/
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt syn match header /^#+\zs.*\ze/ "Why doesn't ^ work?
```

This *sort of* works, but it also matches the `#`s and some incorrect text. It's also **very** slow and takes about ~10 seconds to match on my macbook:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt syn match header /\zs\n#*\w*\ze/
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- these work on online regex testers.

On [this tester](https://regex101.com/), the regex `^#*(.*)` works perfectly, where I'm matching with the first capture group. How do I translate this for vim?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplier for 1 or more matches is `\+`; you forgot the backslash (or the `\v` "very magic" modifier). Using `\ze` at the end is superfluous. `^` matches at every beginning of line `\n` only starting on the second line. Please be aware that Vim uses a special regular expression dialect, so what various web sites tell you may need adaptation. The `:help pattern` pages are the best and authoritative reference.

```
syn match header /^#\+\zs.*/
```

Also, your syntax addition may be obscured by existing syntax rules. You can try appending `containedin=ALL`, but that's not a general solution. You may need to analyze the existing syntax and craft a special solution for each syntax. As an alternative, you may use the `:match` command. This works on top (and independent) of syntax highlighting. The downside is that this is *window-local*, so you need `:autocmd` magic if you want to apply this only to certain buffers, or also to window splits.

```
match header /^#\+\zs.*/
```

#### style critique

With your `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt syn match`, your intermingling several aspects: filetype detection (the mapping of `*.txt` to an (here: implicit) filetype), filetype customization, syntax highlighting). It would be cleaner (and more extensible) to separate the things:

1. Define a `text` filetype: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt setf text`. This detection may already exist in your Vim version.
2. Define syntax highlighting (or extension) in `~/.vim/syntax/text.vim` (or `~/.vim/after/syntax/text.vim` to extend an existing syntax).

Comment: That works great -- thanks for your help! Especially the style critique -- it can be difficult to find the proper conventions.